# Scala - sbt: Is it safe to compile while running?

Tags: scala, sbt

I often have to run some time-consuming experiments in scala, and usually I run a second sbt
instance for the same project where I make changes to the code that is running in the other instance and compile.
The reason I do this is so that I don't have to wait for a long running process to finish before I make progress with my code.

My question is: Is it safe to do that, or is there a possibility that recompiling parts of currently running code in sbt/scala will cause problems in my running process?

What I have observed so far is that most of the time it is fine, but I did run into a class not defined error once when refactoring my code while running.

Comment: Not sure about sbt/scala, but the JVM is certainly capable of lazy-loading classes, so it's possible to be in a situation where a class that has not been loaded yet is changed or removed under JVM's feet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @marcus mentioned, the compiler writing a .class file that has not yet been loaded by your running JVM stands the chance of being loaded and not matching the other compiled classes. In many instances you'll be fine, but it could cause problems. There are a few things you can do in this situation:

1. Compile in separate directories. Check your code out into two completely different directories and do local commits (assuming you're using git) to push/pull from one copy of the repository to another. This will ensure that your testing doesn't get the compilation changes until you're ready (when you "pull" from the development repository).
2. Use an automated CI system like Jenkins or Travis to run your tests on each commit. This will, similarly to #1, not conflict with your development work since it is a separate checkout of the code.
3. Use sbt-revolver which runs the program in a separate JVM with the `re-start` command and will restart it whenever there are changes. This would interrupt your testing, however.
4. Use JRebel which does a better job of reloading classes than the JVM or most IDEs.